# Full references to subordinated sections with cref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

When referring to subordinated sections, cleverref by default shows the identifier of the referred section as it is actually displayed in full text. I redefined the `\part`, `\chapter`, ... commands to display only the identifier of the actual section. Is there a way to show the identifiers of the superordinated section, chapter, part ... as well? Cleveref does not seem to have an option for this and unfortunately I was not able to investigate a solution on my own.

Here is my MWE to demonstrate what I am looking for:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\renewcommand*\thepart{\Alph{part}} 
\renewcommand*\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}} 
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}} 
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand*\thesubsubsection{\roman{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}

\part{First Part}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\label{first_chapter}
Is: For further information see \cref{first_subsection}.

Should be: For further information see section B.II.1.a.

\section{First Section}

\part{Second Part}

\chapter{Second Chapter}

\section{Second Section}

\subsection{First Subsection}
\label{first_subsection}
Is: As noticed in \cref{first_chapter} ...

Should be: As noticed in A.I. ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeX provides a built-in mechanism for adding the "prefixes" of subordinated units to cross-reference call-outs. If a counter called, say, `mycounter` is created, LaTeX automatically creates a macro called `\p@mycounter` which contains the material to be prefixed in a cross-reference to an instance of `mycounter`.

By default, this "prefix macro" is empty, i.e., it inserts no material. However, if you add the instructions

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@chapter}{\thepart.} % prefix for chapter-level cross-refs
\renewcommand{\p@section}{\p@chapter\thechapter.} % prefix for section-level cross-refs
\renewcommand{\p@subsection}{\p@section\thesection.} % for cross-refs to subsections
\renewcommand{\p@subsubsection}{\p@subsection\thesubsection.} % for cross-refs to subsubsections
\makeatother
```

to the preamble of your document, all cross-references generated by `\cref` (and, for that matter, `\ref` as well) to chapters, sections, subsections, and subsubsections will employ the full composite numbers.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for. And I even learned about the counter mechanism.